# connecting external android app to internal server fails

Tags: android, sockets, networking, portforwarding

i am writing an android app that performs logins, sends messages, etc, through a server application that i am also writing. my server is on a wireless LAN. when i connect the android phone to the same WIFI network i am able to get them to connect successfully. the client :

```
PORT = 5555;

 mSocket = new Socket();
 mSocket.setSoTimeout(500);
 SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.0.111", PORT);
 mSocket.connect(socketAddress);
```

and the server :

```
PORT = 5555;
servSock = new ServerSocket(PORT);
Socket sock = servSock.accept();
```

the issue i am having is when i have the server on the LAN and the android phone is attempting to connect using its cellular data connection. i understand that i need to set up port forwarding and i have done so with the starting and ending port set to 5555 for both local and external. i have also assigned the server a static IP on the LAN. also i am attempting to connect to the routers IPv4 address listed under WAN in the router config web portal. when i attempt this it still does not work. i get a socket timeout from the android client everytime. could this be an issue with the subnet mask? or should i be using IPv6 for some reason? how can i attempt to solve this problem? thank you in advance.

Comment: Try connecting to your server with a different client, say a web browser. That way you can work on getting the port forwarding/NAT issues resolved first, and debug the app later.

Comment: @James yes that helped. i had made a mistake and had not changed the IP correctly in one of my async tasks. i was able to connect over browser and then looking a little more closely saw the mistake that i had made. thank you.

Comment: does you have a private IP address from your provider?

Comment: @Vlad no I don't think so. I am just using a static IP on my server and connecting to routers wan address.

Comment: `routers wan address` it might be your provider's inner network IP, not real IP. You have to havwee real IP to connect to your router from the internet

Comment: @Vlad the strange thing about this is that it is working fine now. And continues work fine most of the time. Occasionally though, the application is unable to reach the server. At those times when I try connecting with a browser I expect to see the GET request logged to the server but I don't.  But 20 minutes later both the app and a browser can connect successfully. Why could this be? Just bad internet service? Or something else?

Comment: who knows...? I think that it is not the app's problems.